# Java "Bit Shifting" Tutorial?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

I would be thankful for a good tutorial, that explain for java newbies how in java all the "bit shifting" work.

I always stumble across it, but never understood how it works. It should explain all the operations and concepts that are possible with byteshifting/bitmanipulation in java.

This is just an example what I mean, (but I am looking for a tutorial that explains every possible operation):

```
byte b = (byte)(l >> (8 - i << 3));
```

Comment: It's **bit** shifting, not byte shifting.

Comment: thanks, I updated the heading (you were faster;-)

Comment: You might want to take a look at this page : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141525/absolute-beginners-guide-to-bit-shifting

Comment: For all those interested, besides the answers below, the link from Mike above, is absolut worth to be read!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Well, the official Java tutorial [Bitwise and Bit Shift Operators](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) covers the actual operations that are available in Java, and how to invoke them.

If you're wondering "what can I do with bit-shifting", then that's not Java specific, and since it's a low-level technique I'm not aware of any list of "cool things you can" do per se.  It'd be worth becoming familiar with the definitions, and keeping your eyes open for other code where this is used, to see what they've done.

Note that often bit-twiddling is an efficiency gain at the expense of clarity.  For example, `a << 1` is usually the same as `a * 2` but arguably less clear.  Repeated XORs can swap two numbers without using a temporary variable, but it's generally considered better form to write the code more clearly *with* the temporary variable (or even better, in a utility method).  So in this respect it's hard to give great examples, because you're not likely to achieve anything new or profound on an architecture level; it's all about the low-level details.  (And I'd estimate that a vast number of uses of bit-twiddling "in the wild" are instances of premature optimisation.)

Comment: On the other hand, I like `1 << i` better than `(int)Math.pow(2,i)` (for `i` in the range 0 .. 31).

Comment: @Paŭlo: Actually that's a good example of my point.  While Java is verbose, *I* prefer `Math.pow` here because it declares the intent.  The fact that integers being implemented as binary behind the scenes makes power-of-two arithmetic expressible in less characters (and maybe CPU cyles) as `<<` is an accident of hardware.  In general, bitwise operators should (IMHO) only be used when the object really is a sequence of bytes, and you're doing something like hashing/crypto/compression/etc. - else you risk creating write-only code.

Comment: If there where an integer exponentation operator, I would prefer it, too. But there isn't, and Math.pow is defined on `double` values. (And since Java already used `^` for bitwise/logical XOR, we won't get such an operator.) I think just `1 << i` could be permitted (maybe with a comment `// 2^i` or such).

Comment: Bitwise operates are useful for things such as RGB colors created by BufferedImages.

Comment: As far as "cool operations" goes, the handiest I've ever found is the XOR swap - it lets you switch the values of two variables without having to allocate more memory. In Java, it would be

X = X^Y; 
Y = Y^X; 
X = X^Y; 

Applications may seem limited, but if you're dealing with embedded systems with memory restrictions, or looking to seriously optimize performance, it has its uses.

Answer (score 15):

When using the shift operator, be very careful not to repeat a common error!!

As the following [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141525/absolute-beginners-guide-to-bit-shifting) suggests, the author of the accepted answer mentions:

> **"In some languages, applying the shift operators to any datatype smaller than int      automatically resizes the operand to be an
>   int."**

This is absolutely crucial to remember when operating on bytes for example, otherwise you may get unexpected results (as I did).

Given a byte with the following bit pattern:

```
1001 0000
```

When I tried to bit shift by 4, and assigned to an int, such as:

```
int value = byteValue >>> 4;
```

I would expect to have:

```
0000 1001   (or a value of 9)
```

But I would get a HUGE number!  That's because the *byteValue* is casted to int **BEFORE** the bit shift operation, thus resulting in something like this instead:

```
1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1001
```

Comment: A nice fix for this issue is making a bit mask (in this case, 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1111) and &ing the result with the mask to force removal of potential extended leading 1s.

Answer (score 13):

There is an infinite number of possible combinations. However they will be made up of one or more combinations of

```
>> shift right with sign extension.
>>> shift right with out sign extension.
<< shift left.
```

To get an understanding I suggest you write the binary numbers on paper and work out what happens.  Trying to read it in a tutorial won't guarantee understanding. esp if they haven't helped so far.

Answer (score 9):

There is simple but clear tutorial that I find useful [here](http://www.roseindia.net/java/master-java/bitwise-bitshift-operators.shtml)

Comment: The link does not work anymore.

Answer (score 5):

It's not exactly a tutorial, but I have a personal [library of bit-shifting functions](http://code.google.com/p/mikeralib/source/browse/trunk/Mikera/src/main/java/mikera/util/Bits.java) in Java which you are very welcome to study!

Also if you do a google search for ["bitwise tricks"](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=bitwise%20tricks) you will find a lot of material. Many of these are in C/C++ but are generally trivially to convert to Java as most of the syntax is the same.

Answer (score 5):

Here are the [details of how bit shifting works](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19).
There is some non-intuitive behavior that is not covered by the official tutorial. For instance, the right operand has a limited range (0-31 for int, 0-63 for long), and will not produce a warning if you exceed that range -- it will just truncate the bits (i.e. %32 or %64), which may give behavior other than you expect.

Answer (score 3):

This site seems to give a pretty good tutorial on what you can do with bit manipulation (so not specific to java but since it is pretty easy to translate)

http://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/quiz_bit_manipulation.html

The tutorial above provides

- Bitwise Operations
- Setting and Clearing a Bit
- Displaying an Integer with Bits
- Converting Decimal to Hex
- The Number of Bits Set in an Integer (Number of Ones)
- The Bit Set Position of an Integer
- In-Place Integer Swap with Bit Manipulation
- The Number of Bits Required to Convert an Integer A to Integer B
- Swap Odd and Even Bits in an Integer
- What (n & (n-1) == 0) is checking?
- Two's Complement
- Fliping n-th bit of an integer
- Floating Point Number Bit Pattern
- Bit pattern palindrome of an integer

Here's a file that has a bunch of java implementations

http://geekviewpoint.com/

Answer (score 2):

These are two good tutorials i found while learning about bit shifting, they arent in java but most languages use the same operators and the theory is the same.

1. [Bit twiddling](http://sol.gfxile.net/boolean.html)
2. [PHP Bitwise Tutorial by Jim Plush](http://www.litfuel.net/tutorials/bitwise.htm)