# Meaning of some operator in java

Tags: java

I would like to know what is the meaning of the single & in java, i often saw it during byte operation. I saw that exist the | operator too. And the >> and << operator.

Comment: Google for "Bitwise Operators".

Comment: Or read the specification: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/index.html

Comment: Or the tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Comment: In the future, you can use http://symbolhound.com to look up symbols

Comment: @TimS. Cute. I'll have to remember that

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are bitwise operations?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16162290/what-are-bitwise-operations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The & and | operators are, respectively the AND bitwise and OR bitwise. The >> and << are the bit shifting.