# Can someone explain the practical usage and implementation of masking bits?

Tags: java, binary, bit-manipulation, bit, masking

I am trying to prepare for technical interviews and I noticed a few practice questions involved bit masking and bit shifting. I am unfamiliar with these concepts. I understand that if you are using half of a byte and want to leave the other half available you can mask the 4 bits you want to use, but I am still fairly confused about how this might be easily understood or applied to a coding problem. If someone has sufficient knowledge or some resource that explains this in very simple terms (preferably in Java) I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: For a concrete, real-world example (non java, usually), of a coding problem where they might be applied, it's no accident that the IP networking term "netmask" is called that.

Answer (score 0):

Bitmasks are an effective tool if you have a collection of boolean flags, for which you'd like a compact representation, or if you want to be able to efficiently test for certain combinations of true/false patterns.

For example assume the following (C++, because my Java is quite rusty):

```
enum {
    FlagOne   = (1<<0),
    FlagTwo   = (1<<1),
    FlagThree = (1<<2),
    FlagFour  = (1<<4),

    FlagOneAndFour = FlagOne | FlagFour
};

unsigned int flags;
```

you can now do various tests in a very concise way. For example to test if any of FlagOne, FlagTwo or FlagFour are set you can write

```
if( 0 != (flags & (FlagOne | FlagTwo | FlatFour)) ) {
    /*...*/
}
```

Or if you want to test for FlagOneAndFour being set you can do

```
if( FlagOneAndFour = (flags & FlagOneAndFour) ) {
    /*...*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some examples:

```
int a = 60; /* 60 = 0011 1100 */
int b = 13; /* 13 = 0000 1101 */
int c = 0;

c = a & b; /* 12 = 0000 1100 */ 
System.out.println("a & b = " + c ); // a & b = 12

c = a | b; /* 61 = 0011 1101 */
System.out.println("a | b = " + c ); // a | b = 61

c = a ^ b; /* 49 = 0011 0001 */
System.out.println("a ^ b = " + c ); // a ^ b = 49

c = ~a;/*-61 = 1100 0011 */
System.out.println("~a = " + c ); // ~a = -61

c = a << 2; /* 240 = 1111 0000 */
System.out.println("a << 2 = " + c ); // a << 2 = 240

c = a >> 2; /* 215 = 1111 */
System.out.println("a >> 2  = " + c ); // a >> 2 = 15

c = a >>> 2; /* 215 = 0000 1111 */
System.out.println("a >>> 2 = " + c ); // a >>> 2 = 15
```

But there is already a good and comprehensive [SO question on bit operations in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6250114/java-bit-shifting-tutorial).