# BigDecimal Class in Java - Reason behind Constant values

Tags: java, operators

I am working out with [Java Puzzlers](http://www.flipkart.com/java-puzzlers-traps-pitfalls-corner-cases-bloch-joshua-author-gafter-neal-author-english-pearson-paperback-edition-1st-english-1st/p/itmczzfekh5vnrzn) second puzzle.

```
public class Change {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println(2.00 - 1.10);
  }
}
```

You will think the answer is 0.9.  But it is not.  If you workout this you will get 0.8999999.  The solution given is

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal("2.00").subtract(new BigDecimal("1.10")));
```

Now it will print 0.9.  I understood why it prints 0.89999.  But  while
I am curiously debugging BigDecimal class,  I found there are many constant values substituted in most of the places.  I'll list all those below and interested to know the reason behind it.

[BigDecimal.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/math/BigDecimal.java) line number 394,

```
               while (len > 10 && Character.digit(c, 10) == 0) {
                    offset++;
                    c = in[offset];
                    len--;
                }
```

Here [Character.digit](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Character.java#Character.digit%28char%2Cint%29)(c,10).

```
public static int digit(char ch, int radix) {
        return digit((int)ch, radix);
    }
```

Here 10 is passed as radix.
Q1.  Why 10 is passed there.??

BigDecimal.java line number 732

```
int sign = ((valBits >> 63)==0 ? 1 : -1);
        int exponent = (int) ((valBits >> 52) & 0x7ffL);
        long significand = (exponent==0 ? (valBits & ((1L<<52) - 1)) << 1
                            : (valBits & ((1L<<52) - 1)) | (1L<<52));
        exponent -= 1075;
```

Q2. If you look into the code in depth,  you can understand what the valBits is, and I am unable to understand why rightshift is used some where?

Q3.  Here also you can see there as many constants like 63, 52 are used.  Why?

Q4.  I can understand that the hexadecimal `0x7ffL` used here will increase the speed of execution.  Again why BitWise `&` operator is used there with the hexadecimal constant.

I hope my question is clear.  Sincerely your patience is appreciated.

Comment: Q1 : Assuming the piece of code comes from the constructor of BigDecimal,  the piece of code is decoding the `char[]` representation of the value. Hence a radix of 10.

Comment: Q3 : valBits is a long hence is represented on 64 bits. so valBits >> 63 gives the 64th bit which is the sign bit.

Comment: Q1 Because it's a decimal. Q2-4 because it's decoding a `double.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q1: Of course, the radix is the base of the computation. You're are using a digit in base 10 ;)

Q4: 7ff in binary: 0111 1111 1111

If you read the explanation of the bit shift operators, [Java "Bit Shifting" Tutorial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6250114/java-bit-shifting-tutorial) you will see that >> 63 discard the 63 first bits and keep the last one. The last bit is the sign bit (for signed types). If it is 1 then the integer is negative, hence the int sign there.

Also, you can refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point for the definition of the floating point. The 52 is to distinguish between exponent and significand.

Q4: Of course, for the exponent, you don't want to use the 'sign' bit in it, since it's not a part of the exponent, hence the mask with 7ff. The Bitwise & 0x7ff just do that; it will only put a 0 on the first bit, and leave the other to the same state. (see the truth table of the 'AND' operator https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table)

Edit:

Q4 complementary: If the exponent is for example 12, then the first bit will be something like:

```
0000 0000 1100 ... (positive value) (ex: 1x10^12)
1000 0000 1100 ... (negative value) (ex: -1x10^12)
```

But: 1000 0000 1100 is 2060 decimal.

if you apply the 'mask':

```
  1000 0000 1100 & 0111 1111 1111 -> 0000 0000 1100 (12 decimal)
  AND
  0000 0000 1100 & 0111 1111 1111 -> 0000 0000 1100 (12 decimal)
```

That's what the 0x7ff is for.

Comment: Could you please further brief your answer for Q4.  Like, why that particular hex is used.?