# How to parse bits array to byte array in c#?

Tags: c#, arrays

This question is very close to [Bit array to Byte array in JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42913981/bit-array-to-byte-array), I want to  convert the following bit array to a byte array?

`int[] bits = {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1};`

But different to the answer is the relevant question, I want to store the result **big-endian** which should be:

`0xB5    0x02`

How I suppose to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking how to convert `int` to `ushort`? Any code attempts you can share?

Comment: bits array are not a c# type perhaps you mean byte ? or System.Collections.BitArray ?

Comment: sorry for my expression, I reedited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
byte[] result = bits.Select((x, i) => new {byteId = i / 8, bitId = i % 8, bit = x})
    .GroupBy(x => x.byteId)
    .Select(x => (byte) x.Reverse().Aggregate(0, (t, n) => t | n.bit << n.bitId))
    .ToArray();
```

---

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your code seems not meet the needs. For example, when my bits[] are`1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0` I want the result be `3` not `192`